# What is the difference between linux-server vs linux-image-server on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

I cannot find a recent, definitive difference between `linux-server` and `linux-image-server`. I thought for sure this would be in the Ubuntu documentation, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`linux-server`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-server) depends on [`linux-image-server`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-image-server).

This package will always depend on the latest kernel image available for Server Equipment.

`linux-image-server` = Transitional package

More information can be found in, [“What's the difference between the kernels linux-image-server and linux-image-generic? What architecture is linux-image-server? Which one should I use?”](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq#What.27s_the_difference_between_the_kernels_linux-image-server_and_linux-image-generic.3F_What_architecture_is_linux-image-server.3F_Which_one_should_I_use.3F)

> The **linux-image-server** package is a meta package that will install
>   the latest Server kernel version, while the **linux-image-generic**
>   package is a meta package for the latest Desktop kernel version. The
>   server guide includes some details on the changes made in the Server
>   kernel.
>
> **linux-image-server** is used for both architectures x86 and amd64.
>
> Which one you should use will depend on the type of system you have.
>   If you have a 64 bit processor you can use the amd64 architecture, or
>   the x86 architecture. However, if your processor is 32 bit you can
>   only use the x86 kernel.